# Error de ruta en laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

Estoy tratando de corregir un problema que tengo al acceder a una ruta y tratar de exportar un archivo de excel. La pagina esta en laravel 5 y ha venido presentando algunas fallas por actualizacion y ahora estoy intentando corregir la exportacion del archivo y me indica que no encuentra la ruta; como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo de rutas tengo definida la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::post('/Informes/excelPreventivos', 'InformesController@excelPreventivos')->name('Informes.excelPreventivos');
```

en el controlador:

```
public function excelPreventivos(Request $request)
    {
        $inicio = $request['fechaInicial'];
        $fin = $request['fechaFinal'];        
        $reportes = Reporte_mantenimiento::with('equipo', 'biomedico', 'equipo.clientes')
            ->cliente($request['cliente'])
            ->fecha($inicio, $fin)
            ->get();
        $num = 1;
        foreach ($reportes as $reporte) {
            $data[] = [
                'N°' => $num,
                'N° REPORTE' => $reporte->numeroReporte,
                'CLIENTE' => $reporte->equipo->clientes->nombreCliente,
                'EQUIPO' => $reporte->equipo->nombreEquipo,
                'MARCA' => $reporte->equipo->marcaEquipo,
                'MODELO' => $reporte->equipo->modeloEquipo,
                'SERIE' => $reporte->equipo->serieEquipo,
                'PLACA' => $reporte->equipo->placaEquipo,
                'UBICACIÓN' => $reporte->equipo->ubicacionEquipo,
                'FECHA DE ASIGNACIÓN'=>$reporte->fecha,
                'FECHA DE REALIZACIÓN' => $reporte->fechaRealizada,
                'BIOMÉDICO' => $reporte->biomedico->nombreBiomedico,
                'OBSERVACIONES' => $reporte->observaciones
            ];
            $num++;
        }
        if (isset($data)) {
            Excel::create('Informe Preventivo', function ($excel) use ($data) {
                $excel->setDescription('Informe preventivo');
                $excel->sheet('Informe Preventivo', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
                    $sheet->setAutoFilter('A1:M1');
                    $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
                    $sheet->cells('A1:M1', function ($cells) {
                        $cells->setBackground('#ccf5ff');
                    });
                    $sheet->fromArray($data);
                });
            })->export('xls');
        } else {
            Session::flash('errorMessage', '¡No hay reportes preventivos que correspondan a los filtros escogidos!');
            return Redirect::to('/Informes/preventivos');
        }        
    }
```

y en las vistas tengo lo siguiente:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        @if(Session::has('errorMessage'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                {{Session::get('errorMessage')}}
            </div>
        @endif
        {!!Form::open(['route'=>'Informes.excelPreventivos', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
        @include('Dashboard.Informes.Forms.informe_form')
        <div class="text-center">
            {!!Form::submit('Generar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
            {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Informes / forms

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('fechaInicial','Seleccione fecha de inicio del reporte:')!!}
            {!!Form::date('fechaInicial',null,['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('fechaFinal','Seleccione fecha de final del reporte:')!!}
            {!!Form::date('fechaFinal',null,['class'=>'form-control','required'=>'required'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('empresa','Seleccione la empresa(Opcional):')!!}
            {!!Form::select('cliente',\GeomedicosApp\Cliente::dropdown(),null,
            ['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'empresa','style'=>'width: 100%',
            'placeholder' => 'Selecciona la empresa para generar el informe']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

me gustaria saber en donde estoy fallando o que estoy omitiendo y si hay alguna forma de corregir este direccionamiento?.
muchas gracias por los aportes.

Comment: No tendrías que tener un return en el controller?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ lo tengo en caso que no se pueda hacer la exportacion pero de resto no deberia porque tenerlo

Comment: Es esta https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/ la librería que usas?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ estoy usando esta https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel

Comment: Bueno, es la misma. Por la sintaxis, creo que estás usando la [version 2](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/export.html). Probaste con `return Excel::create(...`. ? Sería raro que un controlador no retorne nada

Comment: lo revisare. Muchas gracias por el aporte.